# What is the result of $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1/n; 1/n)}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I would like to know the intersection of $(-1/n ; 1/n), \forall n \in N$. I am in trouble thinking it could be $\{0\}$ or $\emptyset$. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It is $\{0\}$ because $0$ is in every single one of those intervals, so it is in the intersection.  While anything that is not zero will not be in all of them, just choose $n$ big enough.  So $0$ is the only thing in the intersection.

Comment: I made a *very* minor edit to your post to remove an extraneous "\".  Cheers!

Comment: The Heine-Borel theorem is the more general case of this problem.

Comment: Related post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270949/does-bigcap-n-1-infty-frac1n-frac1n-varnothing

Answer (score 3):

Actually you are right with your first suspicion:

$$
\{0\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (-1/n, 1/n)
$$

We prove this the standard way by showing "$\subset$" and "$\supset$"

"$\subset$":
For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $0 \in (-1/n, 1/n)$.

"$\supset$":
Let $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (-1/n, 1/n)$. This means that $x \in (-1/n, 1/n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This are actually two inequalities:

$\tag{1} x > -1/n$
and
$\tag{2} x < 1/n.$

Both hold for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Taking the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ shows

$x \geq 0$ and $x \leq 0$ which proves $x = 0$.

Comment: do you really mean "$\{0\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (-1/n, 1/n)$"?  what about "$\{0\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (-1/n, 1/n)l$"?  Cheers!

Comment: See you fixed it!  Congratulations!

Comment: @RobertLewis: What a silly mistake. Thanks for spotting it!

Comment: My pleasure, sir!  ***Endorsed!!!***

Answer (score 0):

$$x\in \bigcap_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{-1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)\iff \forall n, |x|<\frac{1}{n}\underset{(*)}{\iff} \forall \varepsilon>0, |x|<\varepsilon\iff x=0$$

The way $\Leftarrow$ of $(*)$ is maybe less obvious. Let's prove it. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\frac{1}{n}\underset{n\to\infty }{\longrightarrow }0$, there is a $N$ s.t. $|x|<\frac{1}{N}\leq \varepsilon$. Therefore $|x|<\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$ (since $x$ doesn't depend on $N$).